# How to enable Mac OS X 10.10 dark mode

Tags: macos, mac

I just updated my MacBook Pro with newest MAX OSX 10.10 and I cannot figure out, how to enable the new "dark mode". Does anybody know how to do that?
Thank you very much.

Comment: Typically, Apple's developer nondisclosure agreements require any discussion of unreleased (e.g. beta seed) products to be confined to Apple's own developer message boards. SuperUser is not the place to violate your license agreements or NDAs.

Comment: Run the battery down to 0% - dark mode engaged! ;->

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about pre-release software